# Chrome Packaged App still throttled in foreground

Tags: settimeout, google-chrome-app

It is well known that Chrome intentionally throttles javascript setTimeout calls for background tabs to a minimum of 1 second, however very recently (Chrome 75 on MacOS 10.13), I have found that my Chrome App is still throttled after returning to the foreground and remains throttled until I close and reopen it, after which setTimeout works as expected.

This does not happen unless the app has previously been in the background or unused for a considerable period of time (e.g. hours). My issue is that returning it to the foreground (i.e. interacting with it) does not speed up its behaviour and I would rather not require my users to close and reopen it.

I have read in other questions on this topic that continually playing audio is a work around. Please can someone point me in the direction of an example of how this can be done natively in a Chrome App i.e. without adding too much bloat.

Comment: This sounds like a bug; it may be more productive to report it at https://crbug.com/ (or, in case you can find it already reported, link it here).

Comment: I have just done so.

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=972973